# Preserve order of `stdout` and `stderr` output of `child_process.spawnSync` subprocess in Node.js

Tags: node.js, pipe, stdout, child-process

```
const spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;
let x = spawnSync('bash', ['-c', 'echo "1stdout" ; echo "2stderr" >&2 ; echo "3stdout"']);
```

(The `bash` command is only an example. The command could be `ls` or `wget` or `git` - doesn't matter.)

Of course, I can access `stdout` of the subprocess with `x.stdout` and `stderr` with `x.stderr` so I will get

```
1stdout
3stdout
```

and

```
2stderr
```

respectively. However, what I want is a single variable which contains

```
1stdout
2stderr
3stdout
```

I have a feeling that there is something in [`options.stdio`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) which could help, but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: You could pipe both stdout and stderr to one stream, which you would in turn pipe to your variable, but I suspect that getting a bug free implementation will be extremely tricky since major companies like heroku often end up with slightly our of order logs when there's a lot of output

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with writing the interwoven output to a file:

```
let fd = createWriteStream('path', options)

// wait on fd 'open' event however you want to.

let results = child_process.spawnSync('ls', args, {stdio: [null, fd, fd]})

fs.closeSync(fd)
```

If you want it as a string then the simplest approach is to just read the file. I think the alternative is to create a duplex stream and pass the stream object in `{stdio: [null, streamObj, streamObj]}`. That would require handling the stream events and building the string on the fly and is probably not required if you're using `spawnSync()`.